# 'gem install' and 'sudo gem install'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

I've got an issue installing gems on my mac (os 10.6).

I used to be able to run

```
gem install <gem-name-here>
```

but after updating *something*, it could be the version of gem I'm using, but it's unlikely, I now get the error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions into the /usr/bin directory.
```

On the face of it, it looks like my 'GEM_HOME' isn't set. If so, why has this been unset, and how can I change it back?

Secondly - when I run

```
gem list
```

I see all gems - including those in ~/.gem, but when I run:

```
gem server
```

I only see gems in /usr/bin... strange huh?

Any help would be great to resolve this - I dont like using sudo to install gems constantly.

Comment: use rvm. it's really a good system to avoid sudo

Comment: What do you get when doing a 'gem env' ?

Answer (score 7):

1. Install [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/).
2. Profit!

It really is that simple. In addition, you will be able to install and easily switch between different Ruby versions and sets of gems with a single command. It will all be installed in ~/.rvm (by default) and you won't need to use sudo to install gems.

Comment: Ok. But this doesn't answer the issue I had

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing `$bundle update` after installing the gems that you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions in [this guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#sudo-less-installation):

```
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH

gem install <gem-name-here>
```

If you were already doing this, completely delete the `~/.gem` directory and try again.